# PHP PDO timeout

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a certain functionality in a PHP page that retrieves through AJAX some data from MySQL.
It is related to obtaining a list of items grouped by categories by giving the categories needed. When the function is called with 1 category, it takes almost a minute to return result and with more than 1, the server gives 500 Internal Server Error and in the log there is:

```
[warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[error] Premature end of script headers: search.php
```

So obviously the query takes too long to execute (the error occurs right at the

```
$query->execute();
```

line - all lines before and no lines after it get executed in the case with more than 1 category which gives 500 ISE).

The problem is that when I run the query through phpMyAdmin by hand, it says

```
Query took 0.8030 sec
```

**What can be causing that huge difference in execution time (less then a second to more than a minute)?**

Note: because there is a random number of categories queried for, I build dynamically the categories part of the WHERE statement using all three columns making up the composite key for a category:

```
$whereCategories = '(';
    for($i=0;$i<count($categories);$i++)
    {
            $whereCategories.= ($i==0?'':' OR ').'(id1=:id1'.$i.
                    ' AND id2=:id2'.$i.
                    ' AND id3=:id3'.$i.')';
    }
    $whereCategories.= ')';
```

And then attach it to the query:

```
$query = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT ... WHERE ... ".
         ($whereCategories=="()"?"":" AND ".$whereCategories).
         " ... ");
```

and bind all the values:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($categories);$i++)
    {
        $query->bindValue(':id1'.$i, $categories[$i]['id1']);
        $query->bindValue(':id2'.$i, $categories[$i]['id2']);
        $query->bindValue(':id3'.$i, $categories[$i]['id3']);
    }

//code runs up to here
    $result = $query->execute();
//code here doesn't run
```

**UPDATE:**
I fixed the performance issue by putting all of the categories values directly in the query string, instead of using `$query->bindValue();`. However, I'd still appreciate it if somebody can explain why the multiple value bindings were working so terribly slow? (even for 2 categories - that's just 6 bindings.)

Comment: why did you run a generic query in phpmyadmin but posted here only stubs of PHP code?

Comment: The function itself is quite large (~80 lines), so I decided to give just the weird part of it - the other lines are mostly some JOINs with static code, which shouldn't be the problem as they don't change.

Comment: function? who said function? it was a *query* I mentioned.

Comment: Well, the function (in the database.php file) is building the query and executing it, so most of it is constructing one big string - the query you're talking about. After that there are just the execute() and return lines.

Comment: Yes. The query I am talking about. So?

Answer (score 0):

If you use "localhost" to connect with PDO, change it to 127.0.0.1
This caused me huge execution times when I learned PDO first time.

Comment: Tried it just now but unfortunately didn't work (yes, I was using localhost).